# Await method never throws error

Tags: c#, .net, sharefile

I am using a library to access the API of a cloud service called [ShareFile](https://www.sharefile.com/). They have a [.NET library](https://github.com/citrix/ShareFile-NET) of methods available, from which I am trying to use the authenticate method called **Password Authentication**, in the documentation. My implementation looks like this:

```
public async Task Authenticate(string username, string password)
{
    try
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Retrieving OAuthService...");
        OAuthService service = new OAuthService(client, clientId, clientSecret);

        Debug.WriteLine("Retrieving OAuthToken...");
        OAuthToken token = await service.PasswordGrantAsync(username, password,
            subdomain, applicationControlPlane); // This line seems to fail

        Debug.WriteLine("Adding credentials...");
        client.AddOAuthCredentials(token);

        Debug.WriteLine("Adding base URI");
        client.BaseUri = token.GetUri();

        Debug.WriteLine("Authentication complete...");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Unable to authenticate", ex);
    }
}
```

The remaining variables, are fields in the class. My problem however is this: The code simply aborts, at the line `OAuthToken token = await (...)`, with no error what-so-ever. Have I done something wrong in the implementation of the method/task, or is it simply the library which is poorly implemented?

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "The code simply aborts"? What sort of project are you running this from, and what are you observing?

Comment: It just seems to end the function. The next line is never reached (i tried adding a break point) and neither is the `catch` section.

Comment: What you are experiencing is known as a *deadlock*. Google "c# async await deadlock", you will find a lot of information.

Comment: "It just seems to end the function" - does it? Or does it actually *never reach the end of the method*. Does the task never complete? If so, it does indeed sound like you've got a deadock.

Comment: @Noceo you are most likely making a blocking call `.Result` or `.Wait()` somewhere higher up the call stack that is causing a deadlock. Start by looking for those blocking calls.

Comment: @Noceo isolate your code and test only the method you posted here. Either create a unit test that calls *this* method only, or copy the code into a separate console application. `await` isn't broken.

Comment: Thank you for you input. It was caused by the wait the method was called, and not the method itself (as suggested). I changed to call to use `Task.Run()` as suggested in the duplicate question.